# How to use Json right for a multi-step select (xml-view / UI5)

Tags: json, xml, select, sapui5

First of all English is not my native language, please ask if anything remains unclear.
I want to make a select in UI5. With this Select option to locate the location of a Rack Unit. MY Goal is that this is a step by step select.
First you chose your Floor.
In Floor 1 for example you have Server Room 1, 2, 3, 4
In Floor 2 you have maybe a, b, c, d
So the Server Rooms are different, then the different Server Rooms have different Server and so on.
How I can structure my JSON or use my controller to do so?

Code example 1, Xml View:

```
 <l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiSmallMargin" >
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="Floor" />
                                <Select
                                    items="{}">
                                    <core:Item text="" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="server-room" />
                                <Select
                                    items="{}">
                                    <core:Item text="" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="server" />
                                <Select
                                    items="{}">
                                    <core:Item text="" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="units" />
                                <Select
                                    items="{}">
                                    <core:Item text="" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
```

Code Example 2, JSON:

```
[
  {
    "server-select": {
      "floors": {
        "floor1": {
          "server-rooms": {
            "server-room1": {
              "server": {
                "server1": {
                  "units": {
                    "unit1": "xXyY11",
                    "unit2": "xXyY12",
                    "unit3": "xXyY13",
                    "unit4": "xXyY14",
                    "unit5": "xXyY15",
                    "unit6": "xXyY16",
                    "unit7": "xXyY17",
                    "unit8": "xXyY18",
                    "unit9": "xXyY19"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this: http://jsfiddle.net/connecttobn/yh6fdanv/

XML would look like:

```
<l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiSmallMargin" >
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="Floor" />
                                <Select width="200px" id="floor" change ="handleFloorChange"
                                    items="{/floors}">
                                    <core:Item text="{name}" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="server-room" />
                                <Select width="200px"  id="serverRoom" change ="handleServerRoomsChange"
                                    items="{/floors/0/serverRooms}">
                                    <core:Item text="{name}" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="server" />
                                <Select width="200px"  id="server" change ="handleServersChange"
                                    items="{/floors/0/serverRooms/0/servers}">
                                    <core:Item text="{name}" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox>
                                <Label text="units" />
                                <Select width="200px" id="unit"
                                    items="{/floors/0/serverRooms/0/servers/0/units}">
                                    <core:Item text="{name}" />
                                </Select>
                            </VBox>
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
```

Dynamically, I am changing the binding of selectable items..